# Override of translations in Symfony not working on localhost

Tags: symfony, translation, symfony4, php-7.2

Here is my problem: I have a project with Symfony 4.4 (php 7.2) and the override of the translations from a bundle does not work on my localhost.

Here is my specific structure:

- in vendor, I have a bundle with a *Resources/translations* directory with a **messages.fr.yaml** file with all my translation key and value pairs.
- And in my project, I have a *translations* directory with a **messages.fr.yaml** file with specific key value pair that I'd like to override those in the bundle.

In my *config/packages/translation.yaml* file you can see the following configuration:

```
framework:
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        paths:
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/company/company-bundle/Resources/translations'
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - '%locale%'
```

On localhost (with the local symfony server — symfony server:start command — or with apache server on local machine) **the override of the translations are not working** (not withstanding the env specified in the .env file), whereas when the project is deployed on our production servers, the override is functionning.

To be precise, we have **all** the translation key/value pairs in the bundle, and in the project directory, we want only to place key/value pair that we want to be taken into account in a more specific way (that is why in the config file we placed the *'%kernel.project_dir%/translations'* path after the bundle one.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: What have you tried to check why this works on one system, but not the other?

Comment: The only difference is that on production servers we are running php 7.3 and nginx, instead of php 7.2 and apache or symfony server. Do you think it can come from this?

Comment: I edit my question to be more precise about what we want to achieve with our structure.

Comment: did you check this issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/40014 ?
I had the same bug and reverting symfony/finder to 4.4.18 solves it. Waiting the fix to be released.